# IAR Workbench: No Definition for "HAL_SPI_Init" error

Tags: stm32, iar

I am using IAR Workbench to compile my codes,

Even I added all Stm32 Hal library in folder and objects>processor in my project

I get this errors:

```
  [ErrorLi005]:  no definition for "HAL_SPI_Init" [referenced from C:\Users\Desktop\Project\EWARM\Project\Obj\api_lib.o
   [ErrorLi005]: no definition for "HAL_I2C_Init" [referenced from C:\Users\Desktop\Project\EWARM\Project\Obj\api_lib.o
   [ErrorLi005]:  no definition for "HAL_USART_Init" [referenced from C:\Users\Desktop\Project\EWARM\Project\Obj\api_lib.o
  [ErrorLi005]:  no definition for "HAL_ETH_Init" [referenced from C:\Users\Desktop\Project\EWARM\Project\Obj\api_lib.o
    ...
    Linking error
```

How can I solve this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't told linker to use the library file, so it cannot find matching symbols which you are using in your object files.

Assuming your library is already compiled (`.a` or `.lib` file), go to *Project > Options... > Category: Linker > Library* and add your library file to *Additional libraries* box.

Comment: I added libraires it solved this problem but I have an another problem now; I get Msp_Init function already defined in another trasnlation unit erorr but I have just one hal_msp.c file in source file .

Comment: A mean I have a hal_msp.c file and this file include Msp_Init functions

Comment: @gogogo Unfortunately I cannot determine the problem based on that description. Since you have new problem, then please ask completely new question.